# What is official name for converting orthogonal coordinates to affine coordinates, but then treating the affine axes as perpendicular

Tags: terminology, affine-geometry

Suppose we had the equation y=x^3 , and then represented our data points as vectors.

Let the unit vectors of our axes be u=1+0i and v=0+1i, then our data point vectors have the form d[n]=x[n]u+y[n]v, for the nth data point.

We then produce a pair of affine vectors,  g and h.

g = ucos(theta)+vsin(theta);   h=ucos(phi)+isin(phi)

We then restate our d[n] coordinates in terms of g and h instead of u and v.

For for theta = 32 degrees and phi = 58 degrees, we get the following image:

d[n] = xu+yv = xu + (x^3)v =  x[2]g+y[2]h

[The apparent transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKGk4.png)

Comment: You are either performing a linear transformation to the plane and looking at the image of the curve under that transformation, or you are doing a change of basis and expressing the equation of the curve in a new basis.  (In terms of the calculations involved these two options are the same thing, but depending on what you want to do next you might prefer to think of it one way rather that the other.)

Comment: I was looking for the official process of examining or expressing a polynomial with affine coordinates.

On this spreadsheet, on the sheet titled 2D Cubic, you can see the transformation taking place:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yXkPCBVWl9kAHh20WPdVmZQ3CL1dTf9nR221Jj1gv_A/edit?usp=sharing

The reason I want to know the name for the official process is because I wish to study the problem further.

For instance, suppose you're presented with the warped image first, is there some method by which we can tell its just a regular cubic, and that our coordinate system is affine?

Comment: Sounds to me like you are interested in expressing the polynomial after a change of basis.  (That is the name of the process: applying a change of basis.)

Comment: So where can I go learn more about the properties of such polynomials?

Google does not yield any fruitful results discussing changes in arclength, roots, etc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The question is in the title:

If you convert (p,q) from orthogonal coordinates for the perpendicular x and y axes to affine coordinates of u and v axes, yielding p[2]u+q[2]v, but then graph the coordinates p[2] and q[2] perpendicular to each other (like in the image in the original post), what is the official name for this transformation.

A change of basis simply means going from (q,p) to (q[2], p[2]) , but a change of basis does not imply graphing q[2] and p[2] orthogonal to each other.

Comment: A transformation that converts orthogonal directions to non-orthogonal or vice-versa is called a "shear" transfomation. There are a few other conditions to separate out translations, rotations, magnification/contraction, and reflection. But all of those do not change angles. The angle shift is the shear component.

Comment: Thank you.  That's all I wanted to know.